# What are the Pokemon CP range for each trainer level?

Tags: pokemon-go

It looks to me that the encountered pokemons CP is based samewhat of the trainers level. Is this the case and are there any data on what trainer level corresponds to what ranges?

I've been saving up all the stardust I've ever gotten because the investment seems risky if at the next level the CP ranges goes way up.

Comment: I think you'll keep catching low cp pokemons every now and then, but the max goes up each level I think.

Answer (score 2):

My data isn't complete as I haven't been actively keeping track, but here is what Iv'e found. Once you reach max CP for any Pokemon at your level, every subsequent level allows you to power up said Pokemon twice. Each power up grants 20-60(level 4-16) CP based off of the Pokemon's initial power and player level. My Lapras maxed out at 971 at level 11, 1056 at level 12, ~1140 (forgot screenshot) at level 13 and 1267 at level 14. +85, +~90, +~120. I have since run out of Lapras candies so i can't pursue this information further until i obtain more. I'll attempt to gather more data using a more common Pokemon later (Eevee evolution probably) and edit when i can, but the stardust needed is hard to maintain.

How this relates to the question:

The encounter CP is a random number between lowest possible (10 in 1st evolution) and maximum possible. From the data we can see that the max CP does increase incrementally so as a result encounter CP will increase at the same rate.

In conclusion, while it is more effective to power up and evolve Pokemon later, the max CP increase seems to be mild enough that from level to level the difference isn't insurmountable.

Comment: false as false it just could be.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the CP of Pokemon you encounter is completely based on your trainer level.

The maximum trainer level cap is 30, i.e. after 30th level, the Pokemon you'll encounter will have the same CP range of the Pokemons that you encountered when you were at level 30.

To answer you question, there's still no exact data mined out about CP of Pokemons after decoding the game files; so, it's still hard to say what exact range of CP Pokemons will you encounter at particular levels. The only thing confirmed is, Pokemon's CP range heavily depends upon trainer's level.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to this nice website: http://poke.isitin.org/, and check for each pokemon the max CP for your trainer lvl.

The tool is quite simple and it is quite intuitive to use, but nevertheless to your question: you can only catch or train a pokemon up to a certain limit that is determined by the players level. Individual pokemon also have some variability in skills: attack, defense, stamina that affect the CP.

Personally I use stardust only in pokemon that I have verified in the site above to have perfect or nearly perfect individual skills and best attacks.

Further speculation:
Eventually if no rule changes are made in the game every player will be lvl 40 and individual skills and attacks of the pokemon will start to matter and the players who have pokemons whose individual skills and attacks are the best are strongest.